# Read input from two files and write them into another file in C

Tags: c, file, input, stream, output

I'm trying to make a program that reads in two files and writes the content from both into a separate file. My program already reads both files and displays their statistics and I just need to get it to write it into the new output file. I think I'm almost there I just need a little help to finish it off. Here is my code: (the output file stream is at the end of the code)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

    // declaring variables
    FILE *fp1;
    FILE *fp2;
    FILE *out;
    int charcount = 0, wordcount = 0, linecount = 1, sentence = 0;
    int charcount2 = 0, wordcount2 = 0, linecount2 = 1, sentence2 = 0;
    int character;
    char first[50];
    char second[50];
    char output[50];
    char ch[200];

    // asking the user for the file names and scanning the names they enter as txt files
    printf(" Enter the first file name: ");
    scanf("%s", first);
    strcat(first, ".txt");

    printf(" Enter the second file name: ");
    scanf("%s", second);
    strcat(second, ".txt");

    printf(" Enter the output file name: ");
    scanf("%s", output);
    strcat(output, ".txt");

    // opening the file stream
    fp1 = fopen(first, "r");

    // if the file cannot be reached, display error
    if (fp1 == NULL) {
        printf("File cannot be opened: %s\n", first);
        return 0;
    }

    // reading and printing the file into the program
    printf("\n---FIRST FILE---\n");
    while (!feof(fp1)) {
        fgets(ch, 200, fp1);
        fputs(ch, stdout);
    }

    // counting the characters, words and lines until the program is finished
    fseek(fp1, 0, SEEK_SET); // sends the file pointer back to the start of the file
    while ((character = fgetc(fp1)) != EOF) {
        if (character == EOF)
            break;
        {
            charcount++;
        }
        if (character == ' ' || character == '.')
        {
            wordcount++;
        }
        if (character == '\n')
        {
            linecount++;
        }
        if (character == '.')
        {
            sentence++;
        }
    }

    // closing the stream
    fclose(fp1);

    // printing the number of characters, words and lines
    printf("\n Characters: %d \n Words: %d\n Lines: %d\n Sentences: %d\n\n\n", charcount, wordcount, linecount, sentence);

    //---------SECOND FILE----------//

    // opening the stream
    fp2 = fopen(second, "r");

    // reading and printing the file into the program
    printf("\n---SECOND FILE---\n");
    while (!feof(fp2)) {
        fgets(ch, 200, fp2);
        fputs(ch, stdout);
    }

    // counting the characters, words and lines until the program is finished
    fseek(fp2, 0, SEEK_SET); // sends the file pointer back to the start of the file
    while ((character = getc(fp2)) != EOF) {
        if (character == EOF)
            break;
        {
            charcount2++;
        }
        if (character == ' ' || character == '.')
        {
            wordcount2++;
        }
        if (character == '\n')
        {
            linecount2++;
        }
        if (character == '.')
        {
            sentence2++;
        }
    }

    // closing the stream
    fclose(fp2);

    // printing the number of characters, words and lines
    printf("\n Characters: %d \n Words: %d\n Lines: %d\n Sentences: %d\n\n\n", charcount2, wordcount2, linecount2, sentence2);

    out = fopen(output, "w");

    fgets(ch, 0, fp1);
    fgets(ch, 0, fp2);

    fclose(out);



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can print it to the terminal, then you can print it to a file! `printf("")`is merely a special way of saying `fprintf(stdout, "")`. So, open a new file pointer to the file you want to print out to, and set that as the target of an fprintf() call. For example,

```
fp3 = fopen(<output file name>, "w")
fprintf(fp3,<string you want to write>)
fclose(fp3)
```

EDIT: I see you were using fputs to print out. This is the same principle as what I mentioned above. Rather than piping to stdout, open a file for writing and pipe there.

Comment: Okay so now I've added this and it manages to write the very last sentence of the second file and nothing more.. making progress though! here's what I have `out = fopen(output, "w");

  fprintf(out, ch);

 fclose(out); ` I'm guessing I need to add a pointer somewhere?

Comment: @rozak Don't keep opening and closing the file. Open it once at the beginning, close it at the end, and do all the writes in the middle.

Comment: @Barmar so where exactly should I be putting the `fprintf`? just before I close the file streams fp1 and fp2? I don't really understand what you mean by "the middle"

Comment: The `fprintf` calls should be in your `while` loop. `open` should be before the loop, and `close` should be after the loop.

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what order you want to write these to the file. Think of it this way- stdout is just a special 'file,' at least in Unix-based operating systems. So, if you're trying to print to the file in the same order you're printing to the terminal, open a file pointer for writing, change those 'stdout's in your fputs() call to the name of that pointer, and then close it at the end

Comment: so I've done this: ` while (!feof(fp1)) {
  fgets(ch, 200, fp1);
  fputs(ch, stdout);
  out = fopen(output, "w");
  fprintf(out, ch);
 }` and it's reading parts of the file but still not properly.. any idea? @Barmar @AndyW

Comment: As @Barmar said, don't keep reopening the file within the loop. Open it once at the beginning, before the loop, and then close it once at the end, after the loop.

Comment: See [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)  `while (!feof(fp1)) { fgets(ch, 200, fp1);...` will copy the last line from `fp1` **twice** since `feof()` doesn't return non-zero until *after* the `EOF` is reached, so the last line is read then written to the output file, `feof()` returns zero, `fgets()` then fails *and leaves the last line read in the buffer* where it gets written to the output file again.